# R Split column containing vectors into multiple columns

Tags: r, vector

I've been researching for quite a while but haven't found a convenient answer to this problem so I am proposing new question although it looks quite simple.

I have a column (gained by using `str_extract_all` function that returns all occurences of regex in string) which contains 0 to multiple items like below:

```
list(c("1/3", "2327/1", "2312/3", "2312/7", "2327/3", "2327/2" ), c("10655/1", "5/2024"), c("1690/1", "1693/2", "1688/5", "721/66" ), c("3675/1", "4233/1", "4232/1", "4232/2", "4235/1", "4235/2" ), c("109/9", "109/10"), c("3042/5", "3042/7", "3043/1", "3043/2",  "3043/3", "1444/4", "1444/5", "1444/6", "2202/3", "3043/3"),      "336/15", "1/3", "1/2", c("1/2", "340/5"))
```

So it combines vectors and individual items.

Now I want to split my_column into multiple columns that contain only the single items (number of new columns being the max length of the nested vectors). How can this be achieved?

Comment: Can you include the `dput` of `my_column`. It would be easier that way

Comment: @Onyambu Like this? ```list(c("1/3", "2327/1", "2312/3", "2312/7", "2327/3", "2327/2"
), c("10655/1", "5/2024"), c("1690/1", "1693/2", "1688/5", "721/66"
), c("3675/1", "4233/1", "4232/1", "4232/2", "4235/1", "4235/2"
), c("109/9", "109/10"), c("3042/5", "3042/7", "3043/1", "3043/2", 
"3043/3", "1444/4", "1444/5", "1444/6", "2202/3", "3043/3"), 
    "336/15", "1/3", "1/2", c("1/2", "340/5"))```

Comment: include that on the question

Comment: also this is not a dataframe

Comment: @Onyambu This is dput of the column I wanted to share. How do I make it a dataframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your data is a list named `dat` you can do:

```
n <- lengths(dat)
max_n <- max(n)
as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, lapply(1:length(n), \(i) c(dat[[i]], rep(NA, times=max_n-n[i])))))
        V1     V2     V3     V4     V5     V6     V7     V8     V9    V10
1      1/3 2327/1 2312/3 2312/7 2327/3 2327/2   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>
2  10655/1 5/2024   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>
3   1690/1 1693/2 1688/5 721/66   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>
4   3675/1 4233/1 4232/1 4232/2 4235/1 4235/2   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>
5    109/9 109/10   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>
6   3042/5 3042/7 3043/1 3043/2 3043/3 1444/4 1444/5 1444/6 2202/3 3043/3
7   336/15   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>
8      1/3   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>
9      1/2   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>
10     1/2  340/5   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>
```

Comment: Works well, thanks a lot! Still wouldn't expect the code to be this complicated.

Answer (score 1):

```
data.frame(t(sapply(my_column, `length<-`, max(lengths(my_column)))))

        X1     X2     X3     X4     X5     X6     X7     X8     X9    X10
1      1/3 2327/1 2312/3 2312/7 2327/3 2327/2   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>
2  10655/1 5/2024   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>
3   1690/1 1693/2 1688/5 721/66   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>
4   3675/1 4233/1 4232/1 4232/2 4235/1 4235/2   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>
5    109/9 109/10   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>
6   3042/5 3042/7 3043/1 3043/2 3043/3 1444/4 1444/5 1444/6 2202/3 3043/3
7   336/15   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>
8      1/3   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>
9      1/2   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>
10     1/2  340/5   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>
```

---

```
 tidyr::unnest_wider(df, my_column, names_sep = '_')

# A tibble: 10 × 10
   my_column_1 my_column_2 my_column_3 my_column_4 my_column_5 my_column_6 my_column_7 my_column_8 my_column_9 my_column_10
   <chr>       <chr>       <chr>       <chr>       <chr>       <chr>       <chr>       <chr>       <chr>       <chr>       
 1 1/3         2327/1      2312/3      2312/7      2327/3      2327/2      NA          NA          NA          NA          
 2 10655/1     5/2024      NA          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA          
 3 1690/1      1693/2      1688/5      721/66      NA          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA          
 4 3675/1      4233/1      4232/1      4232/2      4235/1      4235/2      NA          NA          NA          NA          
 5 109/9       109/10      NA          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA          
 6 3042/5      3042/7      3043/1      3043/2      3043/3      1444/4      1444/5      1444/6      2202/3      3043/3      
 7 336/15      NA          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA          
 8 1/3         NA          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA          
 9 1/2         NA          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA          
10 1/2         340/5       NA          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA
```

---

Data:

```
df <- structure(list(my_column = structure(list(c("1/3", "2327/1", 
"2312/3", "2312/7", "2327/3", "2327/2"), c("10655/1", "5/2024"
), c("1690/1", "1693/2", "1688/5", "721/66"), c("3675/1", "4233/1", 
"4232/1", "4232/2", "4235/1", "4235/2"), c("109/9", "109/10"), 
    c("3042/5", "3042/7", "3043/1", "3043/2", "3043/3", "1444/4", 
    "1444/5", "1444/6", "2202/3", "3043/3"), "336/15", "1/3", 
    "1/2", c("1/2", "340/5")), class = "AsIs")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```